# Create a file with only the changed content from git last two commits

Tags: git

Hi Could anyone help on creating a file with only the changed content(lines) and not any other extra metadata like +'s,-'s or filenames from last two git commits locally

```
git diff 091sd752e7 28cdfbad3
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index 86c6331..73a7c15 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-# agent-conf-data
\ No newline at end of file
+# agent-conf-data
+check
```

so now I want get a file named X.diff with only the changes like

```
$ cat X.diff
agent-conf-data
check
```

Comment: Why is the file named `X.diff`? What about the missing newline? What does your effort so far to do this yourself look like, and what has gone wrong with that effort?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+changed+files+between+two+commits

Comment: `git diff --name-only HEAD~2 > X.diff`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you

```
git diff HEAD~2 | grep -E '^[+-][^-+]' > X.diff
```

how this works:

- get the diff of the last two commits `HEAD~2`
- find all the lines that start with `+` or `-`, but don't have another `-` or `+` following the first
  (NOTE it is valid for a file to do this so it may not work for all cases, for example if it had a diff in it itself! .. if you find this is the case, you should craft your own regex)
- redirect the output `>` to a file named `X.diff`

If you meant to strip the `#` from the first line and it's not really an error, you could chain another piped command before writing to remove 'em or do any other work